# Setting a java ProcessBuilder environment with a bash script

Tags: java, bash, environment-variables, processbuilder

I've been using ProcessBuilder to successfully invoke a process with various environment variables using `env.put("VAR","value")`.

Now I'd like to source some bash scripts to set a whole bunch of environment variables that are not predetermined within java.

Anyone know of an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash` supports the environment variable `BASH_ENV` on startup. Set the variable to your script and its contents will be sourced before execution. See `bash(1)` for details.

Comment: I don't know how to do that? Where can I set BASH_ENV to ProcessBuilder? Is there any function?

Answer (score 0):

If your "batch scripts" to be sourced are in [properties format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties#Format), you can always load them using Properties and merge into the env.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on properties.  Unfortunately its a bash (linux) script, so not properties format...